# Joomla ZOO mod_zoocategory template customisation

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.1

I am looking to customise the way in which ZOO, a Joomla CCK renders the list of categories. I understand that with mod_zooitem it's actually quite simple however I cannot find an actual template file to copy from. Also, Google and YOOtheme (author of the CCK) websites proved pretty unhelpful- YOOtheme only provide a guide for mod_zooitem and not mod_zoocategory.

I am only looking for a point in the right direction of a guide or the dir of the files that render the default category list.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you **can** actually do this in `mod_zooitem` so question was a lack of understanding mixed with a massive wet brain fart.